# PHP/mysql - checking for duplicates in very large table causes hanging

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check for duplicates in one table and delete them from another. It hangs forever and ultimately results in a 500 internal error. Here was my original method in php:

```
$sql_2 = "SELECT account_no FROM customersTable";
$result_2 = mysql_query($sql_2) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
while(list($acct) = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)) {
   $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE(account_no = '$acct')";
   $result_delete = mysql_query($sql_delete) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
}
```

I then tried the following queries instead of the above script, all hang:

```
DELETE FROM tempTable WHERE account_no IN (SELECT account_no FROM tempTable)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM tempTable USING tempTable, customersTable ct WHERE tempTable.account_no=ct.account_no
```

These all hang for 20 minutes or more and then finally there is an internal server error "The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition."

I am open to any and all solutions even ones that do not involve php or involve caching, batching, or whatever it takes.

Comment: Hi there. Can you post the php log for this call? It may be helpful to inspect what exactly throws the 500 error code.

Comment: It does not appear to have logged this.

Comment: you want to delete only the repeated values without keeping a copy?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it to just run it on the MySQL side:

```
DELETE tempTable 
FROM customersTable
JOIN tempTable
ON customersTable.account_no = tempTable.account_no;
```

Comment: Won't this delete records from the customersTable?

Comment: Nope, only from `tempTable` (anything _before_ the `FROM` are the tables that get deleted from). See als [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html): (_"For the first multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed before the FROM clause are deleted."_)